# Android Webview and iOS UIWebview with same html but difference when displayed

Tags: android, html, ios, css, uiwebview

We are developing app for Android and iOS for displaying data from server via API (Data is html). But when set data for webview to be displayed, on Android and iOS has difference.
Suppose web has 3 responses with 3 html(with difference html, css (font size, font name)). But on iOS, font size is same for 3 html, on Android, its has difference between 3 html. I have saved html content to file and open by chrome on windows and iOS. The result on Windows like Android and on Mac like iOS.
I dont know what but I think that has a difference between apples's OS with other OSs.
Anyone know why? Please explain me. Many thanks.
Sorry I can't post html contents to here.